# Prevent JVM Shutdown while Hazelcast(Embedded) executor service thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, hazelcast

I am using Hazelcast IExecutor Service.

I've written test where I submit task to IExecutorService, while executor service thread is still under execution, JVM is getting terminated and hence Hazelcast Shutdown occurs. Hence, test is failing.

Is there any way where I can prevent JVM or test termination while hazelcast thread is still under execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc on [getExecutorService](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/5.0/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance.html#getExecutorService-java.lang.String-) says there is no defined shutdown behavior:

> Note: Note that it doesn't support invokeAll/Any and doesn't have standard shutdown behavior

Unfortunately, there is no way to change that. You can look into the implementation details in [ExecutionServiceImpl](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v5.0/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spi/impl/executionservice/impl/ExecutionServiceImpl.java#L310-L340) class where you can see it waits for 3 seconds to finish before [shutting down the executor](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/v5.0/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spi/impl/executionservice/impl/ExecutionServiceImpl.java#L331). Beware that this can be changed anytime. We are actually looking into making this behavior more defined and maybe even configurable.

Feel free to file a feature request at [GitHub](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues), especially if you shutdown gracefully/terminate, if you access cluster data in the task and what is your expectation if your task takes too long to finish.

Comment: Thanks a lot, will check.

Comment: Currently we are using executorService for task which takes 45 min and our app is containerized. During k8s pod shuffling, tomcat shutdown happens and hence hazelcast shutdown, and if  the task is under execution during this time, it abruptly gets failed with Hazelcast instance not active exception. Could please you suggest a way to stop/postpone tomcat/hazelcast shutdown when task is under execution?